# Best file upload approach

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, image

So, what do you guys recommend to start off from in order to achieve the functions below?

1. Multiple image file upload
2. Resize(compression) images
3. Upload them via ajax (automatically) even before the form is submitted.
4. First image is the "main" featured image, and others are given custom post meta
5. For multiple images, there are radio buttons which users can choose which one becomes the main image.
6. Once form is submitted, any changes (if user changes the main image) will be updated.

I tried to build something from scratch but it is taking too much time.

[image]

Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: _"tried to build something from scratch but it is taking too much time"_ ? Can include `html` , `js` tried at Question ?

Comment: Well, bottom line, "it is not working and I am pulling my hairs out" sort of thing.

Comment: Well, I think I am going to use one of light weight, well documented jQuery plugins and modify it instead of building it from scratch. I did find some online  (such as plupload) but wanted to know what other recommendations are out there.

Comment: Try utilizing `multiple` attribute at `input type="file"` element , `$.post()` at `change` event , create `select` element to select "main image"

Comment: plupload is ideal...UI you are talking about needs custom code no matter what you use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. My way:

   - 1.Use plugin for multiple ajax upload
   - 2.Plugin for resizing images
   - 3.Change main image trough ajax